# Is there a way to send a separate Exact Target email to a contact that is not in Salesforce already?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am looking for information on whether or not I am able to send a "one off" email within Exact Target and just autofill an email address in, even an email address that is not already in my Salesforce account.

I may be looking too deeply into this situation and missing something obvious, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Please look at the [Guided Send](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/guided_send/) feature. It allows you to specify the recipient email. If this is not a one-off but a more ongoing requirement, you should look at using [SMTP Relay](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/sending_exacttarget_emails_via_smtp_relay/).